# Reading all the values from Qtablewidget in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

i have imported a QtableWidget in my Gui. I am a newbie in PyQt and Qt designer.
I need to read the values entered in the cells in the QtableWidget.
My existing code is given below.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

 try:
     _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
 except AttributeError:
      _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

 class Ui_MainWindow(object):
     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
         MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
         self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
         self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
         self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
         self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 80, 256, 192))
         self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
         self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
         self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
         item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
         self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
         MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
         self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
         self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 25))
         self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
         MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
         self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
         self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
         MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

         self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
         QtCore.QObject.connect(self.tableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("cellChanged(int,int)")), self.slot)
         QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

     def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
         item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
         item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
         item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "3", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
         item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "x", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
         item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
         item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "y", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

     def slot(self):
         row= self.tableWidget.currentItem()
         print str(row)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_MainWindow()
     ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

after running this program it i got an error in def slot(self).

Comment: What error?! Please _always_ post the full traceback when asking for help with errors in your code. The indentation is messed up in your example code, but if I fix that, I don't get any errors when the slot is called.

Comment: when i run the above program it display a main window which contains a table with 2 columns x and y. when i enter the values in cells i get the following statements in the terminal,<PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7f1e4e42b950>
<PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x7f1e4e42b950>

Answer (score 1):

that is not error. `self.tableWidget.currentItem()` returns `PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object` , so that is what you get printed.

You want this:

```
def slot(self):
    curItem = self.tableWidget.currentItem()
    print curItem.text()
```